# How to wait all threads to complete a Sampler before starting its Post Processor

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

I have 2 samplers with JSR223 post processors in each. I want threads to wait before starting the Post Processor.

If there are multiple threads are running the sampler, I want to start the Post processor execution after all the threads complete the sampler.

Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to achieve this using JSR223 PostProcessor as all JMeter threads (virtual users) are absolutely independent and will start the PostProcessor as soon as sampler will be completed.

So I would suggest amending your test as follows:

- Sampler 1
- Sampler 2
- [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

  - [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)

The Synchronizing Timer will act as a "rendezvous" point so this way you will be sure that all threads have finished Samplers execution and will start your JSR223 Sampler at exactly the same moment.

If you don't want JSR223 Sampler to generate Sample Result - add `SampleResult.setIgnore()` somewhere in your script.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with little change. Since I am using less number of  Web driver samplers, I set the above things on a Transaction controller. A transaction controller for each sampler and jsr223 sampler has a Synchronizing timer as a child.